# how to convert dzi (deep zoom) files to full image

Tags: deepzoom

How can I convert deep zoom files to a full picture?

[image: http://s9.picofile.com/file/8347459176/Capture.PNG]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a tool for this, but you can probably write one easily. The only folder you need is the highest level (16 in your screenshot). Tile 0_0 goes in the upper left corner, then tile 1_0, etc. wrapping around to 0_1 on the next row.

To get it exact you'll need to take a look at whether there was any overlap when the tiles were created. Look in the .dzi file for "overlap". If there is, you'll need to compensate by omitting the overlap. Here's more info on the file format: https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/wiki/The-DZI-File-Format

Comment: Hello
I found the method
With imagemagick you can grab photo pieces and extract high-quality photos

Comment: Nice! For future reference, what's the method?

Comment: install imagemagick and use this command:
magick -border 0 -geometry 660x -tile 212x212 *.png final.png

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in [libvips](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/) with something like:

```
vips arrayjoin "$(ls *.jpeg | sort -t_ -k2g -k1g)" x.tif --across 20
```

That will find all `.jpeg` files in the current directory, sort the filenames (of the form `x_y.jpeg`) by y first, then x, and assemble them into a grid 20 tiles across.

There's a more complete version of this answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58927878/894763

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of tools for this. Dezoomify and Dezoomify-rs work well, and there is a website version for smaller files/projects too.